# How to initialize python code from the Qt-designer

Tags: python, qt

i have to make a GUI for a project i am working on. Since i am no programmer please excuse my question.

I created the GUI using Qt-designer. I also successfully compiled the .ui file to .py

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Mesher(object):
    def setupUi(self, Mesher):
        Mesher.setObjectName("Mesher")
        Mesher.resize(480, 555)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Mesher)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 510, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Mesher)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 510, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(Mesher)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 450, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Mesher)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 450, 131, 22))
        self.comboBox.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(Mesher)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 351))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.add_coordinates_button = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.add_coordinates_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 100, 51, 41))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../Icons/green-right-arrow-clip-art-6842.jpg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.add_coordinates_button.setIcon(icon)
        self.add_coordinates_button.setObjectName("add_coordinates_button")
        self.list_coordinates = QtGui.QListWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.list_coordinates.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 20, 161, 192))
        self.list_coordinates.setObjectName("list_coordinates")
        self.input_x_coordinate = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.input_x_coordinate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 51, 20))
        self.input_x_coordinate.setObjectName("input_x_coordinate")
        self.input_y_coordinate = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.input_y_coordinate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 110, 51, 20))
        self.input_y_coordinate.setObjectName("input_y_coordinate")

        self.retranslateUi(Mesher)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Mesher)

        def retranslateUi(self, Mesher):
            Mesher.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Mesher", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Save Changes", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Exit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.pushButton_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Import", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.comboBox.setItemText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Engrid", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.comboBox.setItemText(1, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Gmsh", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.comboBox.setItemText(2, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Salome", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.comboBox.setItemText(3, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Abaqus", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.comboBox.setItemText(4, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Ansys", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.groupBox.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "EzMesher", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            self.add_coordinates_button.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Mesher", "Create geometry", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


Ui_Mesher()
```

i tried to initialize it in my main file like:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

import Gui_mesh

class MainDialog(QDialog, Gui_mesh.Ui_mainDialog):

def __init__(self, parent = None):

    super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainDialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

but apparently i can't use Ui_mainDialog. I hope you can help me.

Regards

Comment: Please post error stack trace.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Ui_mainDialog'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the proper name from the compiled .py file?

```
class MainDialog(QDialog, Gui_mesh.Ui_Mesher)
```